# Can't Access Azure Synapse Spark Pool Databases on SSMS

Tags: azure-synapse

Since I've starting using Azure Synapse Analytics, I created a Spark Pool Cluster, then on the Spark Pool cluster I created databases and tables using Pyspark on top of parquet files in Azure Data Lake Store Gen2.
I use to be able to access my spark Database/ parquet tables through SSMS using the Serverless SQL endpoint but now I can no longer see my spark Databases through the Severless SQL Endpoint in SSMS. My spark databases are still accessible through Azure Data Studio but not through SSMS. Nothing has been deployed or alter on my side. Can you help resolve the issue? I would like to be able to access my spark databases through SSMS.

[Sql Serverless Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfowJ.png)
[Azure Synapse Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzC4q.png)

Comment: Logged in to Serverless SQL in SSMS, I can see the Spark database, but the table are listed under External (which makes sense because they are). In Azure Data Studio, they are directly under the Tables folder. But present in both tools.

Answer (score 0):

If your Spark DB is built on top of Parquet files, as you said, databases should sync to external tables in Serverless SQL pool just fine and you should be able to see synced SQL external tables in SSMS as well. Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-spark-tables) for more info about metadata synchronization. 
If everything mentioned above is checked, then I'd suggest you to navigate to Help + Support in Azure Portal and fill in a support ticket request with details of your problem so engineering team can take a look and see whether there is some issue with your workspace or not.

Comment: Thanks. Some how magically the Databases appeared in SSMS the day after I submitted a ticket. I saw the new databases entries added in the [sys].[databases] view on the day the issue fixed it self. No idea what could have caused the databases to disappear in SSMS. I emailed support hopefully they can provide some insight on what happened.